# Кастомный Preference. Секреты создания?

Tags: android, android-preferences

Я создаю приложение, в нем нужно реализовать кастомный Preference как на картинке. Я использую Preference Support Lib v7/v14, но видимо из-за кривых библиотек гугла сделать это не получится.

*На картинке видно, что размер шрифта кастомного дочернего Preference слишком большой и thumb seekBar'a обрезается, неверные paddings/margins*

[image]

Содержание gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:24.1.1'
```

Содержание manifest:

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v14.preference"/>
```

Я искал информацию по этой теме очень долгое время, но так и ничего путнего и не нашел. Действительно, даже на этом сайте, где есть такой вопрос все как ошпаренные быстренько проходят мимо. В чем же заключается неимоверная сложность решения такой незамысловатой задачки?

Большое спасибо за любые ответы!

Comment: Как же я не люблю возиться с библиотеками

Comment: Писал сам адаптер для этого и не парился

Comment: Сергей, какой адаптер? Вы имеете ввиду написали свой аналог Preferences?

Comment: Решил проблему, но не уверен в правильности решения, поэтому выкладывать ответ не буду.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что это гугл сделала "кривые" библиотеки, а не ваши "кривые" руки во всем виноваты? Если вам нужна помощь по коду или оформлению, то необходимо предоставить этот код или оформление (создание преференсов и разметку). Гадание о глючности бибилотек гугл по картинкам тут не практикуется совершенно, видимо поэтому ваш вопрос и обходят стороной, а сложность решения вашей задачи в том, что не предоставлено никакой информации для решения, кроме невразумительной картинки и уверений, что это гугл "глючный"

Comment: pavloff, видимо вы просто не сталкивались с этой проблемой. И вопрос обходят стороной нет только мой, а все вопросы, которые я только мог найти в гугл. Библиотеки действительно с багами. Погуглите. Какую информацию Вам нужно предоставить, чтобы Вам было понятно, что это обычная разметка преференсов? Привести код xml преференсов?

Comment: Да ну это дело. Преференсы это жесть. Да удобно но кастомизация сложная

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих попыток добиться правильного отображения `Preferences` на разных версиях ОС пришел к собственному решению проблемы. Если покажется, что решение неудачное - предложите лучший свой вариант. Прошу заметить, что на подобные вопросы на всем StackOverflow ответа найти не удалось.

И так, для начала переопределите `Preference`, например так:

```
public class PreferenceFix extends Preference {

    private Context context;

    public PreferenceFix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public PreferenceFix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public PreferenceFix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public PreferenceFix(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setPadding((int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.preference_side_padding), 0,
                (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.preference_side_padding), 0);
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    }
}
```

В файле `dimens.xml` укажите отступы:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="preference_side_padding">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Теперь, чтобы пользоваться этим `Preference` просто пишите вместо стандартного:

```
<com.yourpackage.PreferenceFix
    android:key="about"
    android:title="@string/title"
    android:summary="@string/summary"/>
```

SwitchPreferenceCompat, EditTextPreference, ListPreference делайте по аналогии.
Надеюсь данный пример сэкономит кому-то немало времени.

По поводу `PreferenceCategory`. Можно поступить также, а можно определить для каждой версий ОС файл разметки, например:

*layout-v17/my_preference_category_material.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Preference_TextAppearanceMaterialBody2"
    android:textColor="@color/preference_fallback_accent_color"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/preference_side_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/preference_side_padding"
    android:paddingTop="16dip" />
```

А в стиле указываете на новую разметку:

*values-v17/style.xml*

```
<resources>
  <style name="appPreferenceTheme" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
      <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/Preference.MyCategory</item>
  </style>
  <style name="Preference.MyCategory" parent="@style/Preference.Category.Material">
      <item name="android:layout">@layout/my_preference_category_material</item>
      <item name="android:selectable">false</item>
      <item name="android:shouldDisableView">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```